# How to load initial data at creation of a model but the same data have to be editable in Django?

Tags: python, django, model

There's something called the Dictionary. This dictionary is a series of things which every model called store must have attached. So, everytime I create a store, I have to replicate this things in this store. However, this things should be editable too from a global admin, since each store has its own admin.

So, I was thinking into create a separate table with the proto things and then add them when necessary, but I can't find how to create two models with the same structure in Python/Django.

Is there a way to do this, or there's a better way to do the same?

Comment: If your looking at loading data to DB, then you should look at creating your own management commands to do so.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, but perhaps [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) will help?